# Hiding Tab Contents Until Page Loads for Mediawiki Tabber Extension

Tags: tabs, mediawiki

I'm using [this script here called "tabber"](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber) to make tabs on my pages to divide up my content. Specifically, I'm using the tabber script on my Mediawiki pages via [this wonderful plugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aTabber).

However, the problem I'm having is that when you first load any page with the tabs on it, the tabs are fully expanded, then contract to hide the content of the tabs that shouldn't be showing. This causes the page to jump all around until it has fully loaded, which makes the pages look like an absolute mess. (You probably won't see this in the examples on the page above, as the tabs barely have any content in them. If you load the tabs with a bunch of content, as well as content around them, the problem starts to happen.)

In some tab scripts I've seen on the Internet, this doesn't happen. When you load the pages. Nothing moves at all and it seems that when you click the tabs, the content loads for the first time rather than just loading everything at once and then hiding the contents of the inactive tabs. I would like to know if it's possible to modify the Javascript or PHP for the tabber code above so that nothing jumps around - so that when you load the page, you just see the contents of the first tab and then the other tabs either load their own content when you click them or are just loaded with the page but don't just show and then contract. I have extremely limited knowledge with PHP and Javascript, and have been trying to experiment with this problem by comparing the tabber script to other scripts out there in Notepad, but I'm just not having any luck figuring out what to change.

Thank you so much in advance! I greatly appreciate any help at all! :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that [someone on Tabber's Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/barelyfitz/JqZi3D9i-B4) came up with a solution several years ago, but I wasn't able to get it working when I tried it this week. Maybe the code they came up with can help shed some light on what I'm trying to accomplish.